# How to Boot to Mirrored ZFS Drive

Tags: zfs, solaris-10, mirroring, zpool

I would like to clone an existing operating system environment. I currently have a Solaris 10 running ZFS mirrored drives on a Sun Fire x4100 box.

Can I take one of the mirrored drives, remove from the current x4100 box, insert into another x4100 box and boot?

What commands need to be used to accomplish?

Comment: Do you have a backup of this system you can restore instead?

Comment: Existing ZFS snapshots / backups include only specific directories where the applications and data are stored. We want to clone the entire operating system. What would a typical clone procedure be for a ZFS system? Should I create a snapshot of the entire system?